# Unable to fix Undesired Output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a issue with getting my desired output (Shown after code)
I have tried several different ways and nothing seems to have worked.
The following code is just what I left off with when attempting to fix the issue

```
song_list = []

def get_songs(): # Just gets all songs ready and loaded for other things
    global song_names
    global song_amount
    global song_list
    ############### Variables
    songs_in_folder = list(os.listdir(input_folder)) # Grabs all files in folder Will add for actual .osz detection later on for this stage.
    song_list.append(songs_in_folder) # Adds to song_list which is currently just used for testing else where.
    # Checks if files are even in folder or not, does not check extentions, must fix in the future
    if songs_in_folder >= 1:
        song_amount = 1
    else:
        print("No Songs were found in the directory!")
        time.sleep(2)
        exit()
    ############### Code to clean up file names for users and stuff
    for elem in songs_in_folder:
        beatmap_name = elem[6:] # Cuts off the first 6 characters which are always 6 different numbers ex) 827212 nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica => nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica

        songs_in_folder = string.strip(beatmap_name,'.osz') # Removes file extention '.osz' leaving just each songs name => nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica
        ######## Add song number and name together
        song_list = ("[",song_amount,"]",songs_in_folder) # Fixes lists look without numbers or .osz extention. Easy to read this way.
        song_amount = int(song_amount)
        song_amount = song_amount + 1
        song_list = str(song_list)
        song_list = ''.join(song_list)
        print(song_list)

get_songs()
```

Issue:

Output results in: `('[', 18, ']', ' nameless - Milk Crown On Sonnetica')`

While the desired output/result should be: `[song_number] Song name`
Please note that `song_number` is really just `song_amount`

A more visual example of how this should look `[18] nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica`

If anyone has any questions or comments, please comment off this question and I will get back to you as soon as I see it.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  This is a lot of overhead code for what seems to be nothing more than a question on output formatting, which you could solve with a tutorial on the topic.

Comment: The code I posted is minimal compared to many other of my posts.
I even cleaned it up just for stack overflow.
The reason I posted ALL related code is because I don't know why the problem is occurring.

Ive attempted different methods Ive seen and all of them just result in the same issue. Ill attempt to clean it up some more removing any non-important things such as globals, etc

Comment: Investigating what is redundant, and what is relevant, is part of what we expect before you post.

Comment: Im talking about unnecessary code in terms of use. (Something that is or could be done elsewhere) 

I removed quite a bit of things that aren't relevant and the only other things I can see would be just the 3 global variables that are called on...

Comment: If all of that code is required to produce the problem, then the answer I'd posted doesn't apply, and neither does the one you accepted.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with string-formatting. You seemingly didn't test the steps your algorithm is composed of in isolation, so you didn't know where to watch for the error.

These are possible solutions for your problem:

```
song_amount = 18
songs_in_folder = "nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica"

'[%d] %s' % (song_amount, songs_in_folder)
# '[18] nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica'

'[{}] {}'.format(song_amount, songs_in_folder)
# '[18] nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica'

# or for Python 3.6+
f'[{song_amount}] {songs_in_folder}'
# '[18] nameless- Milk Crown On Sonnetica'
```

The main takeaway should be, that you test every step possible *before* you compose a lenghty function out of it.